# How to reference a string-array resource with a String that is the id?

Tags: java, android, xml

Apologies for the terrible title, but couldn't think of a better one. So I have numerous string-array's in my strings.xml file. I want to be able to reference this by passing my intent the resource id (e.g. R.array.mystringarray) as a string, and then using this string in my class to get my String[].  Here's what I have attempted so far to give you a better idea of what I'm trying

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Main.this, Categories.class);
intent.putExtra("category", "R.array.Categories");
startActivity(intent);
```

Then in Categoris.class:

```
myArrayID = (String) bundle.get("category");
myArray = getResources().getStringArray(myArrayID)));
```

Is my method even possible? Or is there another way I've overlooked. First app and still learning the ropes

EDIT - sorry, my head is fried tonight and I totally confused myself here. I have re-written the question - [Converting "R.id.myID" from a String to the int value R.id.myID?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7117102/879896)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure why you wanna do this, but you can pass the int ID directly:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Main.this, Categories.class);
intent.putExtra("category", R.array.Categories); //R.array.Categories is an int value
startActivity(intent);
```

Then..

```
int myArrayID = bundle.getIntExtra("category", 0); 
myArray = getResources().getStringArray(myArrayID)));
```

Comment: Honestly feel so stupid ha, released this after I posted the question. Thanks though

Answer (score 0):

Try this in Categoris.class

```
String myArrayID[];
myArrayId=bundle.getStringArray("category");
```

Answer (score -2):

Not much of an answer, but that is correct: see [getStringArray](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html#getStringArray%28int%29). You will want to cast it correctly, but otherwise you got it right.

Comment: The Resource getStringArray() method takes an int as input. If she wants to use a String, she needs to use the Bundle getStringArray() method.

Comment: No, `Bundle.getStringArray` does NOT return a Resource array. The type being put into the Intent extra is incorrect, but the method of choice I listed IS is correct. Not sure why the downvotes, but I stand by the method I pointed to.