# How to reference a string array in XML of Android layout file

Tags: android

The closest I could find on S.O. is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7116640/how-to-reference-a-string-array-resource-with-a-string-that-is-the-id) but it doesn't answer it.

It specifies [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource.html#String) how to make a resource reference for a string, i.e. `@string/string_name` but further down under String Array in the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource.html#StringArray), it gives no option under Resource Reference for referencing the string array in XML like it does further up for String.

Comment: It simply isn't possible but there are some workarounds that could work for you, like this one here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30465202/how-do-i-call-string-array-value-in-xml-layout

Comment: It would be like `@array/string_array_name`, but the attribute you use it for has to be able to take an array.

Answer (score 0):

It's unclear what element you are trying to load the array into...

`ListView` has `android:entries` that accepts `@array/` resource.

However, I find that adding adapters in the code makes more sense.
 [`ArrayAdapter.createFromResource`](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/spinner.html) allows you to use an a String Array XML resource to load either a Spinner or a ListView using `R.array` in Java code.

Comment: I think Mike M. basically answered my question, i.e. what I was looking for was `@array/string_array_name` for use in a ListView. I guess based on the first comment and what i've seen as these adapters basically being a workaround for the `@array` feature not being available previously, or am I totally off on that assessment?

Comment: It would be nice if `@array` could be used like that, but a ListView in the XML does not know the layout used by the adapter (or if there is an adapter available) at the inflation step of that parent layout

Comment: So are you saying basically you can only get a crude output? I.e. I tried this http://theopentutorials.com/tutorials/android/listview/android-creating-and-populating-listview-items-in-xml/ and it "works" (list items are shown without having to program an adapter) but are you saying it really doesn't work in some way?

Comment: Ah, yes, I forgot about that attribute